# Bulk email sending issue with Ubuntu 14.04 (Linode VPS)

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, email, postfix

I have an email server on Linode.com with the following specs:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Apache & MySQL
- Postfix, Dovecot, Spamassassin, Postgrey, RoundCube, sievemail components.

**Problem:** Everything works fine but when I try to send bulk email to more than 15 recipients, it gives the error "Too many recipients". I am using Microsoft Outlook 2010 to send and receive emails and I see this error in MS Outlook.

**My questions:**

1. What could be the possible issue and how to solve it?
2. Is there any limit set in **Postfix** which is not allowing to send bulk email? How to uplift that limit?

Comment: It would be nice if you add more in detail.. as to what sort of mail server you have set-up,... etc.

Comment: Also, where are you seeing this message? Do the mail logs offer any other clues?

Comment: Might be a limit imposed by Linode VPS: http://www.msoutlook.info/question/198

Comment: Yes, there is a limit in Postfix, but it is 1000 by default. What is the output of `postconf | grep smtpd_recipient_limit`?

Comment: @fkraiem output is 16

Comment: Then this is specified somewhere in your Postfix configuration files, and you should just modify it.

Comment: @fkraiem I just modified the value and it solved the issue. Thank you so much for your swift help. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postfix does indeed have a limit on the number of recipients in a single message, which is specified by the [`smtpd_recipient_limit`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_limit) configuration directive. Its default value is 1000, but it can (of course) be modified in Postfix's configuration files. To obtain its current value, run

```
postconf | grep smtpd_recipient_limit
```

In this case the limit was set to 16, and so Postfix rejected messages with more than 16 recipients.